# How to go to Particular page in angular ag grid server side pagination?

Tags: angular, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have implemented server side pagination using angular ag grid. If user click on arrow then next page data get rendered in grid. I want to implement a feature that is if user edit one record which is on page 4 and after edit if he want to come back then after refresh the user should navigate to page 4 where he was previously , but ag grid is loading from page 1. Anybody can help how to go to particular page for server side pagination.

I have tried to use params.api.paginationGoToPage(4) but this only work for client side pagination when ag grid get all the data. can anybody suggest how to implement the same for server side?